# What properties of $A:H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])\to H^{1/2}([0,2\pi])$ allow us to bound the Sobolev operator norm of $A$ by the $L^2$ operator norm?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have an operator $A:H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])\to H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])$ where $H^{s}$ is the fractional Sobolev space of order $s$.

I want to bound the $||\cdot||_{H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])\to H^{1/2}([0,2\pi])}$ operator norm with the $||\cdot||_{L^{2}([0,2\pi])\to L^{2}([0,2\pi])}$ operator norm. Here's what I've done so far:
$$
\begin{align}
||A||_{H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])\to H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])}^2 & = \sup_{||\phi||_{H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])}=1} ||A \phi||_{H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])}^2 \\
& = \sup_{||\phi||_{H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])}=1} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (1+|n|^2)^{-1/2} |\widehat{A \phi}|^2 \\
& \le \sup_{||\phi||_{H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])}=1} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}  |\widehat{A \phi}|^2 \\
& = \sup_{||\phi||_{H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])}=1} ||A \phi||_{L^{2}([0,2\pi])}^2.
\end{align}
$$

Now I need to somehow replace the $||\phi||_{H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])}$ in the supremum with $||\phi||_{L^{2}([0,2\pi])}$ to have a bound of the operator norm $||A||_{H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])\to H^{-1/2}([0,2\pi])}$ in terms of $||A||_{L^{2}([0,2\pi])\to L^{2}([0,2\pi])}$.

What properties of the operator $A$ would allow me to do this?

Or is this never possible?

Comment: The first inequality in your chain is using $\sqrt{1+n^2} \le 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?  This is clearly not true.

Comment: @Glitch You're right, I specified the range of $A$ incorrectly, it should be $H^{-1/2}$ instead of $H^{1/2}$. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is that there are continuous inclusions $i_1:L^2\hookrightarrow H^{-1/2}$ and $i_2:H^{1/2}\hookrightarrow L^2$, hence the concatenation $A'=i_2\circ A \circ i_1:L^2\rightarrow L^2$ is continuous and hence bounded. This is exactly the bound you're looking for. (This uses the fact that a linear operator between normed spaces is bounded if and only if it is continuous.)

Comment: This shows that the $L^2-L^2$ operator norm is bounded above by the $H^{-1/2}-H^{1/2}$ operator norm, but I believe OP is asking for the opposite inequality.

Comment: I had a typo in the the range of $A$, it's fixed now. And Glitch is correct, I am trying to bound the $H^{-1/2}$ norm by the $L^2$ norm.